# Parse Multiple doesNotMatchKeyInQuery

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am having a problem using Parse queries in javascript. I want to try and use multiple doesNotMatchKeyInQuery functions but it only allows the last one to be used. Any ideas how I can make code like this work? Ignore the errors that might exist in other parts of the code. I wrote this as an example

```
//Query 1
var Class1 = Parse.Object.extend("Class1");
var class1Query = new Parse.Query(Class1);
class1Query.equalTo("id", id1);

//Query 2
var Class2 = Parse.Object.extend("Class2");
var class2Query = new Parse.Query(Class2);
class2Query.equalTo("id", id2);

//Query 3
var Class3 = Parse.Object.extend("Class3");
var class3Query = new Parse.Query(Class3);
class3Query.equalTo("id", id3);

//Bringing it all together
var finalQuery = new Parse.Query("User");  

//This is the part below I am talking about
finalQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "id1", class1Query);
finalQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "id2", class2Query); 
finalQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "id3", class3Query); 

finalQuery.find({
    success: function (results) { 
        response.success(results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible to do such a complex query in a single request. However, you can fetch the keys you don't want to match ahead of time, and construct a secondary query from that.
I've written up an example based upon your code above:

```
// Assuming we're actually dealing with 3 different classes,
//   and these can't be combined into a single query
var class1Query = new Parse.Query('Class1');
class1Query.equalTo('id', id1);
var class2Query = new Parse.Query('Class2');
class2Query.equalTo('id', id2);
var class3Query = new Parse.Query('Class3');
class3Query.equalTo('id', id3);
// Fetch the results from all three queries simultaneously
Parse.Promise.when([
  class1Query.find(),
  class2Query.find(),
  class3Query.find()
]).then(function(results) {
  // results will contain three arrays of results
  // We can now build a query where the objectId is not equal
  //   to any of the objectIds of the results
  var ids = [];
  results.forEach(function(set) {
    set.forEach(function(obj) {
      ids.push(obj.id);
    });
  });
  return new Parse.Query('FinalClass').notContainedIn('objectId', ids).find();
})
```

I want to caution you that this query will not be efficient for large sets of data. "Does not equal" queries are never fast, because they have to loop over every object in the table. If there is another way to get your data, I highly encourage it.

Comment: I actually think this does not work. Only one of the queries are populating the results instead of all of them.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. For anyone who is wondering each .find method needs to be accompanied by a results var in the function return. It would look like this

    ]).then(function(results1, results2, results3) {

Comment: @Midevilworm Can you please write the full answer?